# OpenDKIM fails to start

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, opendkim

I'm trying to install OpenDKIM on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

It simply does not start.  First I was starting it through the systemd service, but running it from the command line produces the same result.

I run with strace and it shows it loading a bunch of shared libraries, opening /etc/passwd then quitting with return code 0.

No log messages, no errors, it just silently quits.

Tried running as root and as opendkim, same result.

What other tests can I do?  It seems to have little in the way of logging options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved it.

Ran opendkim with the -f to prevent forking then found it put more info in log files when run from the command line (rather than just quitting).

Running through ltrace hinted at the issue as the last system call was fork().

Found it was nothing more than a unix socket permission.